# OpenGL - Using glTexImage2d to fill the entire screen with a texture

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

Two questions -

What is the best way to use a texture in OpenGL to fill the entire window?

I want to use glTexImage2D to take in an array of ints containing colour data, how would I go about doing this? (I've found a couple of pages of reference on glTexImage2D but tutorial on using it would be great)

**Clarification:**

I have done texturing before. I simply need help on these two *specific* parts.

Answer (score 3):

glTexImage2D just uploads texture data, nothing more. When you have your texture, draw a texture mapped quad the size of the screen and you will draw your texture pixels to the screen.

A ortographic projection is usually used for this.

Comment: How do you make sure it fills the screen and avoid the frustrum getting in the way etc.?

Comment: @ShimmerGeek: Don't use a frustum; use an ortho projection instead. glOrtho(0,1,0,1,-1,1); with a quad with lower left corner at (0,0) and upper right at (1,1) with the same texture coordinates gives you a window filling quad.

Answer (score 0):

NeHe provides tutorials for almost any OpenGL topic.

The first lesson on using textures is [#6](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06).

Answer (score 0):

Also you could just upload the pixels with `glDrawPixels` if you don't need to update to much.

There is a nice example from Nehe on how to use textures [here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06):